# Querying lexemes by number of occurrences in ts_vector in PostgreSQL 9.4

Tags: postgresql, nlp, postgresql-9.4, tsvector

Is it possible to query PostgreSQL using a WHERE statement based on the number of times a lexemes appears within a ts_vector?

For example, if you create a ts_vector with the phrase "top hat on top of the cat", can you `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ts_vector @@ {the lexeme 'top' appears twice}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
create or replace function number_of_occurrences(vector tsvector, token text)
returns integer language sql stable as $$
    select coalesce((
        select length(elem)- length(replace(elem, ',', ''))+ 1
        from unnest(string_to_array(vector::text, ' ')) elem
        where trim(elem, '''') like token || '%'), 0)
$$;

select number_of_occurrences(to_tsvector('top hat on top of the cat'), 'top');

 number_of_occurrences 
-----------------------
                     2
(1 row)
```

Of course, the function works properly only if the vector contains lexemes with positions.

```
select to_tsvector('top hat on top of the cat');

                   to_tsvector                   
-------------------------------------------------
 'cat':7 'hat':2 'of':5 'on':3 'the':6 'top':1,4
(1 row)
```

Example of using the function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM a_table 
WHERE ts_vector @@ to_tsquery('top')
AND number_of_occurrences(ts_vector, 'top') = 2;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the core question, which is the ability to use a WHERE clause to find occurrences of lexemes. Thanks for the input so far, though!

Comment: Thanks! As a supplement, do you know scalable this is? I have 2 billion messages to search, and the ts_vector is already indexed.

Comment: I am afraid the function is too expensive for such amount of data. You should obligatory use the index in the search query, like in the updated example.

Comment: I have rebuilt my function for performance, eliminating costly `regexp_` functions. Now the function should be several times faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `unnest` and `array_length` for this purpose

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (
  SELECT array_length(positions, 1)
  FROM unnest(ts_vector)
  WHERE lexeme = 'top'
) = 2
```

I don't think this will be able to use a GIN index on `ts_vector` but this will likely be faster then the string operations performed in the accepted answer function.